# Orbit Space of Action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{E}^n$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm trying to solve problem 28, chapter 4 of M. A. Armstrong's Basic Topology :

> Describe the orbits of the natural action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{E}^n$ as a group of linear
> transformations, and identify the orbit space.

I take the norm function as an identification map and try to use the fact that $\mathbb{E}^n$ with this identification is homeomorphic to $[0,1)$.

I know each orbit of action $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{E}^n$ is the same as an equivalence class of identification space but I need to show that the identification space and orbit space of acting $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{E}^n$ are homeomorphic to claim the orbit space is homeomorphic to $[0,1)$. Can anyone help me to show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps if I unwind the notation of this problem for you, it will be more evident what you have to do.

Let me introduce some notation for the norm function, say,
$$N(\vec p) = \|\vec p\| = \sqrt{p_1^2 + \cdots + p_b^2}
$$
What you have to prove is that the set of orbits of the action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb E^n$ is *equal to* the set of subsets of the form
$$S_r = \{\vec p \in \mathbb E^n \mid N(\vec p) = r\}, \quad r \in [0,\infty)
$$
Of course, if $r>0$ then $S_r$ is the sphere of radius $r$ centered on the origin, and $S_0 = \{\vec 0\}$.

The next main step is to prove is that the orbits of the action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb E^n$ are precisely the spheres $S_r$ of radius $r>0$ and the set $S_0$, and I'll assume that you know how to do that.

The final step involves applications of concepts of [quotient maps and quotient topologies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) One must check that:

- The norm function $N : \mathbb R^n \to [0,\infty)$ is a [quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map).

Once that has been checked, one must then apply

- The [universal property of quotient maps.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties)

It follows that

- $N$ induces a homeomorphism from the quotient topology on the orbit space of the action to the space $[0,\infty)$.

If these things are unfamiliar to you, you'll have to learn about quotient maps and quotient topologies. I suggest a good topology book, such as Munkres "Topology".

Comment: I looked at $SO(n)$ as group of rotations, so each orbit is precisely a sphere or origin. I also use the facts that action of $SO(n)$ is transitive and each $A \in SO(n)$ is isometry. But I'm still confused in some technical details mentioned in question.

Comment: How much do you understand about quotient maps and quotient topologies? Perhaps that's the main issue for you?

Comment: I added a few more details on the topic of quotients.

Comment: I cannot believe someone downvote you on question like this.

Comment: @LeeMosher Do we know that the topology on the collection of $S_r$s is precisely the topology on orbit space? If yes, How?

Comment: The collection of $S_r$'s **is** the orbit set. And, by definition, the topology on the orbit set **is** the quotient topology.

Comment: See for example [this wikipedia page on quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)), and its two subheadings [quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map) and [the last bullet point under examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Examples).

Comment: For related points of view on the orbit space topology in other math.stackexchange questions see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042305/coset-space-and-orbit-space-of-group-action) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805412/how-to-arrive-at-this-quotient-topology-on-an-orbit-space)/

Comment: You can also find a discussion of the quotient topology as applied to orbit spaces in many topology textbooks; I suggest Munkres "Topology".

Comment: @LeeMosher I couldn't find my answer in these sources. Let me ask it more clear: The quotient space induced by $N$ has a topology. The orbit space of the action has another topology. You claim they are same due to homeomorphism. How?

Comment: The answers were in my answer already, but I have rewritten it to lay out the three main steps in three bullet points. Outside of that, you'll have to learn about quotient maps and quotient topologies.